# Update object in array by Id

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a document in mongodb that stores books read by a user.I want to be able to update the data read field given a book_id. How can I do this in a mongo query? Example would be if book_id =111111 update "date_read" to April 5 2020.

```
{
   _id:"1456786576454",
   books:[
     {
       "book_id":"132451",
       "date_read":"Jan 20 2020"
      },
      {
        "book_id":"111111",
        "date_read":"Feb 5 2020"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You would use `update` with the [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) array operator

Comment: @Joe-im not familiar, can you give me a example?

Comment: that `$` is a link to the docs, with an example